# displaying image in cell header

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

I need to display an image in cell header. The problem is I'm using a class that contains various methods for GUI and I can't figure out how to use cellPaint event in my class. Is there another way how I can update it from my class, the same way I could update a cell value or it has to be cellPaint event? Thanks!

EDIT:

```
class GUI {
   public void FixGridCells(DataGridView grid){

   }

   public void AssignCellImages(DataGridView grid){
      grid.Column[0].Header = myImage; // <-- This is what I need
   }
}

// MyForm.cs

MyForm_Load(){
   GUI gui = new GUI();
   gui.FixGridSize(myGrid);
   gui.AssignCellImages(myGrid); // <-- I need to call it like this
}
```

Comment: Are you using Win forms ? What is mean of Cell Header is it Coloumn Header ?

Comment: @NeerajDubey Sorry, I'm using WinForms and I ment Column Header, thanks!

Comment: I have posted Win form Code please refer.

Comment: @NeerajDubey, thanks, but that's the solution that doesn't work for me, because I'm using a class to handle datagridview. Please check my updated question, thanks!

Comment: Please refer this link hope it will work for you.[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/2ab8kd75.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need to create an Image object from the image file.

```
Image IconImg = Image.FromFile("C:\\logo.jpg");
```

After That use Datagridview Cell painting Event.

```
 private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex == DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & !DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(IconImg, e.CellBounds);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, but I already explained I need to call this from class and I'm not sure how to use cellPaint event in my custom class.